# c# sorting numbers from lowest to highest

Tags: c#, sorting, numbers

I have 5 random numbers each in separate label and would like to sort them form lowest to highest and place them in new label.

Example:
Labels with random numbers from 1 - 60.

```
number1.Text = 42
number2.Text = 51
number3.Text = 12
number4.Text = 33
number5.Text = 26
```

I would like to place that numbers form lowest to highest each in separate label.

Example:

```
sortNumber1.Text = 12
sortNumber2.Text = 26
sortNumber3.Text = 33
sortNumber4.Text = 42
sortNumber5.Text = 51
```

So far I try to place all sorted numbers in one label with this code:

```
private void button63_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var orderNumber1 = Convert.ToInt32(number1.Text);
    var orderNumber2 = Convert.ToInt32(number2.Text);
    var orderNumber3 = Convert.ToInt32(number3.Text);
    var orderNumber4 = Convert.ToInt32(number4.Text);
    var orderNumber5 = Convert.ToInt32(number5.Text);
    int[] numbers = { orderNumber1, orderNumber2, orderNumber3, orderNumber4, orderNumber5};
    Array.Sort(numbers);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    { 
        selected_number1.Text = (numbers[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

But only last (highest) number was entered. If something doesn't make any sense it's because I am noob. Solution that I will understand would be great. Thank you.

Comment: create a List<int> and parse the text in as integers and then use the sort function.

Comment: you're only updating one label, selected_number1.. Shouldn't you update all of them?

Comment: I would create `List<int>` and then use the `OrderByDescending<>` function to sort them.

Comment: thanks for your anwsers. MarcinJuraszek aneser correctly :) thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change entire design here (create a list of labels and use it to iterate over your labels), but for now you can make it work replacing your `for` loop with following:

```
sortNumber1.Text = numbers[0].ToString();
sortNumber2.Text = numbers[1].ToString();
sortNumber3.Text = numbers[2].ToString();
sortNumber4.Text = numbers[3].ToString();
sortNumber5.Text = numbers[4].ToString();
```

Comment: thanks. this really helped me... I just added .ToString(); after each number[0], number[1], etc. and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single string, you need to concatenate them. Probably the easiest way is with LINQ:

```
var numStrings = numbers.Select((i) => i.ToString());
selected_number1.Text = string.Join(",", numStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{ 
selected_number1.Text = (numbers[i].ToString());
}
```

In your loop you are setting `selected_number1.Text` each time so that's the only one getting set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] numbers = { orderNumber1, orderNumber2, orderNumber3, orderNumber4, orderNumber5 };
Array.Sort(numbers);
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all though you have already answered....

```
 List<TextBox> tBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
        tBoxes.Add(number1);
        tBoxes.Add(number2);
        tBoxes.Add(number3);
        tBoxes.Add(number4);
        tBoxes.Add(number5);
        List<int> allNums = new List<int>();

        foreach (TextBox item in tBoxes)
        {
            allNums.Add(int.Parse(item.Text));
        }


        allNums.Sort();
        for (int i = 0; i < tBoxes.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            tBoxes[i].Text = allNums[i].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate over your sorted array, you repeatedly set the same control to the current value with this statement:

```
selected_number1.Text = (numbers[i].ToString());
```

I'd probably do something along these lines:

```
Label[] display  = { Sorted1 , Sorted2 , Sorted3 , Sorted4 , Sorted5 , } ;
Label[] unsorted = { Label1  , Label2  , Label3  , Label4  , Label5  , } ;
int[]   sorted   = unsorted.Select( x => int.Parse(x.Text) ).OrderBy( x => x ).ToArray() ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
{
  display[i].Text = sorted[i].ToString() ;
}
```